# What is the option '-mindepth' doing in this command?

Tags: find

I am using the `find` command of bash, and I am trying to understand it since it is part of a code that I am using. In the code, the command in question is -

`find -L $RAW_DIR -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*.bam" -o -name "*.sam" | wc -l`

I have been trying to understand this command by searching its components. In esence, I thinking it is trying to find the number of files that end with `.bam` or `.sam`. I think `-maxdepth 2` means to search for these files in this folder and its immediate subfolder.

What I do not understand is what `mindepth -2` does in this case. I looked up mindepth, and the explanation given everywhere is -

"*Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative integer). '-mindepth 1' means process all files except the command line arguments.*"

To me this explanation is not very clear. Just like `maxdepth -2`means search for subfolders upto a depth of 2, what does `mindepth -2` correspondingly mean, in simple language?

Also, if mindepth is just the opposite of maxdepth in terms of the direction (which would make intuitive sense), then how do I understand the fact that executing the command above on a folder that does have a `.bam` file leads to the output  **0**, whereas omitting the mindepth part of the command leads to the output **1** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depth 0 is the command line arguments, 1 the files contained within them, 2 the files contained within depth 1, etc.

`-mindepth N` tells to process only files that are at depth >= N, similar to how `-maxdepth M` tells to process only files are at depth <= M. So if you want the files that are at depth 2, exactly, you need to use both.

Your command would match `$RAW_DIR/foo/bam.bam`, but not `$RAW_DIR/bar.bam`.

Try, e.g.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d
$ find ./a -maxdepth 2
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
$ find ./a -mindepth 2
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/d
$ find ./a -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2
./a/b/c
```

`maxdepth` with a negative argument doesn't mean anything:

```
$ find ./a -maxdepth -2
find: Expected a positive decimal integer argument to -maxdepth, but got ‘-2’
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Although I was sort of confused by the words deeper and lower, but I got it eventually

Comment: @user1993, yeah, that didn't come out right. I suppose the opposite of "deep" is "shallow", but that doesn't really sound fitting here. Edited, hopefully for the better.

Comment: Depth implies the hierarchy of a file system. Why are "command line arguments" considered part of the file system?? Perhaps you could clarify that this means the root/starting point of the find i.e. the directory passed as an argument.

Comment: @Marc, fine, "for the purposes of the `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options, the files named on the command line are considered to be at depth 0; files contained within them at depth 1; and in general, files contained within files at depth N are considered to be at depth N+1."  better?

Answer (score 1):

The `-mindepth 2` and `-maxdepth 2` parameters together limits the scope of `find` to the directories at depth two from `$RAW_DIR`.

The `find` command is identical to the `bash` shell command

```
printf '%s\n' "$RAW_DIR"/*/*.{sam,bam} | wc -l
```

This would count the number of `.sam` and `.bam` files in subdirectories of `$RAW_DIR`.  It would still give the count of 1 for no files though, but just like the `find` command, it would count a file with a embedded newline in its name as two files.

For an absolutely correct `find` command, one that counts filenames containing embedded newlines as *one* file:

```
find . "$RAW_DIR" -type f -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 \
    '(' -name '*.bam' -o -name '*.sam' ')' -exec echo x ';' | wc -l
```

This would output an `x` on a line on its own for every found file matching the criteria, and the `wc -l` would count these x-es.